# Clean URL with .htaccess only works for one variable

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use the .htaccess file to make clean URLs for my PHP website. The site is wrapped in the Bootstrap framework.

I can manage to get the clean URL for one variable ($page) but when I try to introduce a second ($user) it fails. I have done this on other sites before with success and I have used that working code.

The code almost works but here's what's happening. When I click [Users] (mysite.com/users) I get the list of users from users.php. When I click [User 1] (mysite.com/user1), I can see the info for User 1. This is ok and is how I want it.

But when I click [About] on the User 1 page, it echos "Info about User 1" as it should but all the Bootstrap css is stripped away and it's plan HTML without formating. It is as if the URL skipps index.php where the css stylesheets are and just prints out the plain code.

So, does anyone see what I've done wrong?

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&user=$2
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'];
?>

<a href="/home">Home</a>
<a href="/users">Users</a>

<?php
if ($page == "home") { include('home.php');
} elseif ($page == "users") { include('users.php');
} elseif ($page == "user1") { include('users.php');
} elseif ($page == "user2") { include('users.php');
} else { include('home.php'); }
?>
```

**users.php**

```
<?php
$user = $_GET['user'];
?>

<a href="/user1">User 1</a>
<a href="/user2">User 2</a>

<?php
# chose user
if ($page == "user1") {
    echo "User 1 <br>";
    echo "<a href='/users/user1'>About</a>";
} elseif ($page == "user2") {
    echo "User 2 <br>";
    echo "<a href='/users/user2'>About</a>";
} else {
    echo "No user chosen";
}

#Show user info
if ($user == "user1") {
    echo "Info about User 1";
} elseif ($user == "user2") {
    echo "Info about User 2";
}

?>
```

Comment: So the issue is just that the CSS isn't loaded? Not that the .htaccess doesn't work? Make sure that you link your CSS with a initial `/`: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path-to/style.css" />` and not just `href="path-to/style.css"`, since the latter will make the browser check relatively from the URL location. The same goes for all resources (images/js/etc.)

Comment: Add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` to fix

Comment: Both your suggestions worked individually! :) Thanks guys!